# Get content of a div class and store to database table using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to get the content of a specific `div class="className"` from a website and then store the content to database.I use this block of code but `var_dump` shows nothing.Please help me because I am totally inexperienced in that.

**Code:**

```
<?php

  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->loadHTMLFile('http://www.someLink.com');

  foreach( $doc->getElementsByClassName('Classname') as $item){
    $class =  $item->getAttribute('div');
    var_dump($class);
 }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

DOMDocument->getElementsByClassName doesn't seem to be a function that exists.

**Try instead using xpath like so:**

```
<?php
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTMLFile('http://www.image-plus.co.uk/');

    $finder = new DomXPath($doc);
    $class_name = "green";
    $nodes =  $finder->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $class_name ')]");

    $tmp_dom = new DOMDocument(); 
    foreach ($nodes as $node) 
    {
        $tmp_dom->appendChild($tmp_dom->importNode($node,true));
    }
    $innerHTML.=trim($tmp_dom->saveHTML()); 
    echo $innerHTML;
?>
```

**Edit:** Fixed mistake

Comment: I get this as a result `object(DOMElement)#3 (0)`.Is this the whole content?Is it possible to store it to database table?Thanks!

Comment: It may be that you grabbed the code before I changed my mistake! If you run the exact code above do you get a line of text? It may be worth creating a separate question for the database aspect as it's quite a big task on its own

Answer (score 0):

i have created one example which is fetch content from div. This content you can easily stored in database.

```
$html = file_get_html('Your website');
$element = $html->find('div[id=Your id]', 0);
echo $element;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written a small function that can create an array of the div elements found inside the class

```
<?php

function get_links($url,$classname) {

    // Create a new DOM Document 
    $xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

    //To remove all unnecessary errors
    $internalErrors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

    // Load the html into the DOM
    $xml->loadHTMLFile($url);

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);

    $classes = $xpath->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classname ')]");

    for ($i = $classes->length - 1; $i > -1; $i--) {
        if(!empty($classes->item($i)->firstChild->nodeValue)){
            $result[] = $classes->item($i)->firstChild->nodeValue;
        }
    }
    // Restore error level
    libxml_use_internal_errors($internalErrors);

    return $result;

}


  $url = 'http://www.example.com';
  $classname ="someclass";
  $rows=get_links($url,$classname);

  var_dump($rows); // YOu will get an array of the contents that you can store in database
  foreach($rows as $row){
   //insert DB command
  }

 ?>
```

Comment: I get this as a result `array(1) { [0]=> string(7) " " } `Is this normal?

Comment: can you give the url and class name you are trying?

Comment: I tried this and I got 9 results in array  `$url = 'http://www.sify.com';
  $classname ="description2";
  $rows=get_links($url,$classname); var_dump($rows);`

Comment: Link is: `www.skroutz.gr/m/2999/Afasia` and the class name is: `rating-summary cf`

Comment: Which class you want to extract?

Comment: name is: `rating-summary cf`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117203/discussion-between-amit-ray-and-platanas20).

Comment: I checked your example and it is perfect..I cannot understand what goes wrong in my site.Can you?